# Why won't the elements placed within my <div> show up?

Tags: css, reactjs

As simple as this:

```
{this.state.dash ? 
                <div className='dashWrapper slide'>
                  HELLO
                </div> : null}
```

No matter what I put inside this div NOTHING shows up. I am literally fuming because I've been at it for so long and I cannot see any reason this won't work. The div itself shows up perfectly fine but anything inside it is a no go.

CSS:

```
.dashWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;

    background: white;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -100%;

    -webkit-animation: slide 1s forwards;
    animation: slide 1s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    100% {bottom: 0;}
}

@keyframes slide {
    100% {bottom: 0;}
}
```

PLEASE SOMEONE HELP ME BEFORE I BREAK MY KEYBOARD :(

Full JSX

```
<div className='pageWrapper'>
          <div className='slides'>
            <div className='one' grey={this.state.grey}>
              <div className='chineseHeader'/>
              <div className='englishHeader'/>
              <div className='mePhoto'/>
              <div className='featuredWorkDivider'/>
              <div className='dash' onMouseDown={() => this.setState({grey: '1', dash: true})}/>
              <div className='allWorksDivider'/>
              <div className='allWorks'>
                <h1 className='work' onMouseDown={() => this.setState({grey: '1', busy: true})}>Busy Map</h1>
                <h1 className='work' onMouseDown={() => this.setState({grey: '1', oke: true})}>Oke</h1>
                <h1 className='work' onMouseDown={() => this.setState({grey: '1', scav: true})}>Scav Hunt</h1>
                <h1 className='work' onMouseDown={() => this.setState({grey: '1', van: true})}>Vanstrings</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
            {this.state.dash ? 
              <div className='dashWrapper slide'>
                <h1 className='back'>Back</h1>
              </div> : null}
            {this.state.busy ? <div/> : null}
            {this.state.oke ? <div/> : null}
            {this.state.scav ? <div/> : null}
            {this.state.van ? <div/> : null}
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: post complete code, it seems like ```this.state.dash``` is false

Comment: With only the context given there's no reason it shouldn't appear. Will need more info, preferably a basic reproducible sandbox

Comment: it is not because I see the div being rendered in -- the animation plays and everything. Updated with full code.

Comment: Post the rest of the your JSX please.

Comment: @codemonkey updated with the full JSX.

Comment: Seems like the HELLO slides from the bottom to the top and then disappears from view. Is that the idea? Are you trying to get the HELLO to slide up like that? Or are you simply trying to make it appear?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your dashWrapper class to look like this.

```
    .dashWrapper {
        width: 99%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: white;
    }
```

Note, that this might break other stuff, but taken alone, this tweak should fix your slide up. Tough to advise on CSS without the full context of the app.

Comment: referring to your comment earlier, basically I am covering the entire screen with a new div. The Hello is just filler content for the div, not actually what Im planning to have inside it. but regardless it wont show up...

Comment: @ZKJ Then add width: 99%; to it. See the edited version.

Comment: @ZKJ So what's the desired behavior?

Comment: https://kaijun.netlify.app/ have a look here (click the dash section, you'll need to scroll a bit). The div should slide up and just stay, which it does. The problem is any content I add in the div is invisible.

Comment: in fact, even if you inspect element the div that slides up you'll see that the content is there but for some reason just invisible? I made sure the font color is different from the background too...

Comment: @ZKJ So what exactly is the issue here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-pine-chr9m?file=/index.html

Comment: I have no clue. I'm guessing its not a problem with the code but rather something else? My code is no different from your working examples...

Comment: Then the issue is likely with some other CSS your page may be pulling.